# Reason: image not found Trace/BPT trap: 5

Tags: macos, dyld, opencascade

I have a problem while running executable on mac OS X(Yosemite 10.10.5 ).
I cloned and builded an open cascade library and there is an executable in directory for testing. When I type ./DRAWEXE on command prompt, I got following result.

```
dyld: Library not loaded: libTKDraw.10.dylib
  Referenced from: /Documents/Practices/openSourceProjects/oce/bin/./DRAWEXE
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: What does `otool -L /path/to/DRAWEXE | grep TKDraw` show?

Comment: libTKDraw.9.dylib (compatibility version 9.0.0, current version 9.0.0) How can I install this library?

Comment: OK, so there is no path (like `/usr/local/lib` for example).  The dynamic linker cannot find it.

Comment: I know the path of libs but I do not know how can I set from command prompt?

Comment: `install_name_tool`.

Comment: Actually, I tried this: install_name_tool -add_rpath Users/Brky/Documents/Practices/openSourceProjects/oce/lib/libTKDraw.9.0.0.dylib DRAWEXE  But DRAWEXE is still not working..

Comment: `rpath` is a path, not a filename (remove the `.dylib`) and then change the reference from `libTKDraw.9.0.0.dylib` to `@rpath/libTKDraw.9.0.0.dylib`.

Comment: I tried this: install_name_tool -add_rpath Users/Brky/Documents/Practices/openSourceProjects/oce/lib/oce-0.16 where libTKDraw.9.0.0.dylib and the result is : DRAWEXE (for architecture x86_64) option "-add_rpath Users/Brky/Documents/Practices/openSourceProjects/oce/lib/oce-0.16" would duplicate path, file already has LC_RPATH for: Users/Brky/Documents/Practices/openSourceProjects/oce/lib/oce-0.16  So it is still not working